# which is best application to set the Mock location in android

Tags: android, geolocation, mocking

which is best and consistent application to set the Mock location in android ?

i have tried some free applications in play store

eg:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lexa.fakegps

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.ajeje.fakelocation

The problem with these apps and the sample app in developer.android.com
 is
it is not consistent. some Location apps does not get the mock location
set by these apps(some does). and also in some phones these mock location
apps fails.

my requirement is testing solution for Location based app. but I am not able to set
the mock location consistently across apps

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Eclipse's Emulator Control Panel contains location controls for each
>   type. To open it, click Window > Open Perspective > Other… > DDMS from
>   the Eclipse menu.
>
> It supports the following three geolocation data types:
>
> ```
> Manual: For setting the location manually by specifying longitude and latitude values.
> GPX: GPS eXchange file
> KML: Keyhole Markup Language file
> ```

[image]

[More Details.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html)

Answer (score 0):

Well AFAIK these mock location app fails in many cases due to location strategy changed from  google playservices in actions.

So u can test your application by using the mock locations as defined [here](http://developer.android.com/training/location/location-testing.html). Here you can set current location and path. the sample app has been attached in the zip.